# pip inatall python's libraries via pip

Tags: python, pip, installation

I am trying to instal xlrd, panda  for my python version 3.6

I am using window 10. By way of input:

```
pip install xlrd
```

from my window command. 
I cannot proceed install and I have the following in return:

> 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

Does anyonw know why and how can I get round it. I am the sole user of this PC so I am not sure what can go wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Is pip installed?

Comment: I have installed the get-pip.py. Not entirely sure if that is the directory  not correct or what

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, pip comes with Python 3.6 version (while installing you have option to select pip to install)

If you have already installed. You can see if pip is installed in this path

C:..\Python\Scripts\

If so, then you have to add this to PATH Environment Variables

That will solve your problem!

Comment: Yup they are installed. Got it. Thanks

Comment: Did you set the path, if you don't know how to set the path, chck this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTUlp6L2zkw

Comment: @kchoi if I have answered your question then please accept the answer by clicking the check mark beside the answer. It would be helpful to other users as well. Thanks!

Comment: @ Sri09 Done it.  Just wonder I did not need to go into the scripts directory to install why in this case we have? I am not sure.. Thanks again

Comment: If you set the PATH in the Environment Variable, then you do not need to into Scripts directory to install tools with pip. It's OS job to directly allow us to access to run executable programs or other programs like pip by searching them in the path directory that you have already set.